# java.lang.ClassNotFound exception when running java from the command line

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to understand the usage of `java` and `javac` better to compile and run applications from the command line.

My project structure is the following:

```
+ lib
    - mylibrary.jar
+ out
    + at
        + mypackage
            - Main.class
+ src
    + at
        + mypackage
            - Main.java
```

The `.jar` file just contains the class `at/mylibrary/Test.class`.

From the `src` directory I run:

```
javac -cp "../lib/*" -d "../out" at/mypackage/Main.java
```

This seems to work. The `out` directory and all its contents are created. Now I move into the `out` directory and try to run it:

```
java -cp "../lib/*" at.mypackage.Main
```

Thats where I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. The main class `at.mypackage.Main` cannot be found.

These are the contents of the `Main.java`:

```
package at.mypackage;

import at.mylibrary.Test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.hello());
    }
}
```

Inside the `.jar` file there is just this one class:

```
package at.mylibrary;

public class Test {
    public static String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong? How is compiling and running this project with `javac` and `java` from the command line done?

PS: I know that it is way easier, especially for larger projects, to do this with a built management tool like Maven, but I really want to know a little more about how this works in general. I searched StackOverflow for suggestions but I could not get it to work.

EDIT: I got it to work. I navigated to the `out` directory and ran `Main` with the following command:

```
java -cp ".:../lib/*" at.mypackage.Main
```

I don't know what I got wrong the first time but now it worked. Like it was suggested in the comments you have to include the current directory `.` in the classpath because when you supply the classpath via `-cp` the default classpath, which includes the current directory, is overridden. At least that's how I understand it. `:` separates the directories from each other.

Comment: You need to add the 'out' directory (`.`) to your classpath

Comment: So the command would be `java -cp ".:../lib/*" at.mypackage.Main`? I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Yea I noticed that before you replied and edited it. I tried `:` and it does not work too

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with how I create the `.jar` file? Because when I change the code in `Main.java` to not access the `.jar` file at all compilation and running the main class works. I just create it as I've seen at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html with `jar mylibrary.jar at/mylibrary/*`